# OpenCV Contrib Python missing functions in ximgproc

Tags: python, opencv

I cant find certain function when I list everything inside opencv-contrib ximgproc module. What am I missing?

Here is a "pip freeze" output:

[image: 1]

Here is a list from dir(cv2.ximgproc):

[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Now, when I look at the source code OpenCV.sln I can see that some of the functions of "ximgproc" are not listed here and some are, for example "createQuaternionImage" which I can easily see inside the source code:

[image: 4]

Where can I look for other functions that are not listed when runnin dir(cv2.ximgproc)?

Thanks!

I have tried couple of "modules"(in the list output of dir(cv2.ximgproc)), I thought that it may be that some functions are on deeper level, but no luck with that.

Comment: those are screenshots of text. please replace with the text the contain. -- [tour], [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every (C++) API of OpenCV is exposed to Python.

The main modules are mostly covered. Stuff in contrib is more likely to lack annotations for Python bindings.

If any bindings are missing, you can DIY and try slapping a `CV_EXPORTS_W` to the declaration. There's a description of this somewhere... just copy what you see in other header files and see what the bindings generation script thinks about it.

Or open an issue and wait until someone gets around to it.

To my knowledge, there isn't a list of APIs that *haven't* been given the required annotation. It makes no sense to ask for that.

Comment: That's what I did eventually and succeeded! Thank you